# Error in expression tree: System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'message' of type 'A' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, expression-trees

I need to build `Action` which will represent this code:
`(new P()).Handle(argument type of A)`

I have an expression for this:

```
Expression.Lambda<Action<A>>(Expression.Call(Expression.New(typeof(P)),
typeof(P).GetMethod("Handle", 
  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public), 
  Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), 
  "message")), 
Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), "message"))
.Compile();
```

But it's throw an error when I'm trying to compile it. Error is:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PerformanceBenchma
>   rk.Test' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'message' of type 'PerformanceBenchmark.A' referenced from scope '', but it is not
>   defined

My code looks like this:

```
public class A
{
}

public interface IInt<T>
{
    void Handle(T item);
}

public class P : IInt<A>
{
    public void Handle(A item)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static readonly Action<A> _expr = Expression.Lambda<Action<A>>(Expression.Call(Expression.New(typeof(P)), typeof(P).GetMethod("Handle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public), Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), "message")), Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), "message")).Compile(); 
}
```

my goal is to measure how fast `_expr(new A())` will be calling. But now it's fails on expression compilation.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - it'll be *much* easier to help you if we can reproduce the problem. I'd also strongly advise you to split that single statement into several separate ones.

Comment: I update question body

Comment: Hint: it will be a simpler exception if you do this in a `Main` method instead of in a static field initializer... and that lets you use multiple statements easily, making the code much more readable.

Comment: The same error when running from main: {"variable 'message' of type 'PerformanceBenchmark.A' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"}

Comment: Yes, you'll get the same error - but when the code is easier to read, it's easier to help you... (I'm adding an answer now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `Expression.Parameter` twice, so you've got two different parameter expressions. They don't bind by name, unfortunately.

So the solution is simply to use multiple statements, creating a `ParameterExpression` *once* and then using it twice. The code is much easier to read that way too:

```
var method = typeof(P).GetMethod("Handle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), "message");
var ctorCall = Expression.New(typeof(P));
var methodCall = Expression.Call(ctorCall, method, parameter);
var expressionTree = Expression.Lambda<Action<A>>(methodCall, parameter);
var compiled = expressionTree.Compile();
```

Of course to initialize a static field with that code, you'll either need to put it in a helper method or in a static constructor.